# Configurar correctamente los archivos manage.py y settings.py en un proyecto web

Tags: python, django, servidor

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto web científico en django y aunque mi web funciona, debo de tener mal configurada alguna cosa en los archivos manage.py y settings.py.
Si pueden ayudarme e indicarme qué cambios debo realizar en estos archivos sería de gran ayuda, pues no tengo formación y me resulta muy complicado el paso a producción de forma correcta.

manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "geologyacademy.settings")
try:
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
except ImportError as exc:
    raise ImportError(
        "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
        "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
        "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
    ) from exc
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for  project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 
...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'xxx'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xxx.xx.xxx.xx',
'xxx.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'...',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'xxx.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'xxx.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-
validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator
',
},
{
    'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
] 


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-es'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),

]



STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")
```

La estructura en mi servidor es la siguiente:
1./ 2.home 3.usuario 4.mysite 5.myapps.... 5.static 5.venv 4.static
La seguridad no es un problema, es una web para alumnos de ciencia.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, ¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: Realmente no lo sé. La web funciona, pero no sé si he hecho bien el paso a producción porque en alguno de los cursos que seguí habla de incluir sentencias MEDIA_ROOT. El caso es que tengo fotos y se ven en la web.Luego he puesto debug false, y no sé si con esto basta porque no entiendo la documentación de django. Y luego que al hacer python3 manage.py runserver no consigo trabajar en local y la terminal responde: File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

Comment: Entiendo, en este caso donde no sabes cual es el problema y no nos muestras el error que quieres solucionar, nosotros no podemos hacer nada al respecto. 

Nos estás mostrando parte de tu proyecto sin ningún problema a resolver en específico.

Comment: Hice algunas cosas y ahora sale esto a python manage.py runserver:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Comment: voy a usr/bin y ahí tengo python python2 python3 y python3.5 No puedo entrar en esos directorios (si es que son directorios). ¿Dónde instalo django?. El problema me vino al quitar el windows y poner Ubuntu.